# What happened to Gobuntu?

Tags: derivatives, history-of-ubuntu

Some time ago there was available an official Ubuntu derivative named Gobuntu that was using free software only. I think I have not noticed when it was abandoned... Why is it no longer continued?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Wikipedia:

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Gobuntu

Because Ubuntu now incorporates a "Free Software Only" optional installer, the Gobuntu project was rendered redundant in early 2008. As a result Canonical made the decision to officially end the Gobuntu project with version 8.04.